# Mostrar un blob en firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdf

Estoy tratando de mostrar un PDF en una pagina HTML pero no muestra nada en firefox, he intentado en chrome y ahi si muestra, utilizando el siguiente codigo.

```
   <div ng-if="downloaded">
       <object ng-bind="pdfcontent" data="{{pdfcontent}}" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="800px">
          </object>
   </div>
```

En mi controlador tengo el siguiente codigo obtengo un base64 de un servicio REST y lo convierto a blob asignandoselo a la variable `pdfcontent`

```
        var blob = b64toBlob($scope.listaDocumentosById[index].docto, $scope.listaDocumentosById[index].tipo_docto);
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $scope.pdfcontent = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);
        $scope.downloaded = true;
```

he intentado usar la funcion `window.open(fileURL);` pero solo muesta el pdf en chrome mas no en firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Puede revisar https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872086/6287771

```
// base64 string
var base64str = $scope.listaDocumentosById[index].docto;


var binary = atob(base64str.replace(/\s/g, ''));
var len = binary.length;
var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
}

// Creamos el blob content-type "application/pdf"               
var blob = new Blob( [view], { type: "application/pdf" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```

Comment: Mira por favor [answer]. Podrias explicar un poco mas porque esto solucionaria el problema?